# TFS Check-In Error - Folder Mappings

Tags: .net, tfs, workspace

I originally had my source code located at:

c:\vs projects\myapp\dev 1.0

I had the workspace mapped there previously and worked on the project from there.  However, my project architect wanted us to standardize the folder and not use versions in the folder names, so I changed it to:

c:\vs projects\myapp

Everything seemed to work fine with that (I actually had my machine reimaged, so I did this when I moved over).  I have one issue though where one file in a project is still looking at the old c:\vs projects\myapp\dev 1.0 root location, for just this one file.  Any ideas how I can fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sounds like you have a pending check-in for a different item?  Just undo that item from the pending changes window.  If that doesn't work, do the following:

- Download and install the TFS Power Tools
- Use the "Find In Source Control" by status and find all files that are checked out to you.
- Find the offending file in the list.
- Right click the file and choose "Undo"

(note, find in source control is a right-click on a folder in your Source Control Explorer window).

Comment: Undo was the right solution; undoing removed it from source, and I could delete/re-add it to the solution, which mapped to the new folder.  Thanks.